# Push segue from 2 sections in tablevew dosent work

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, storyboard, segue

I have a tableView that is configured to Push Segue to another view.
The table is devided into 2 sections.
When i push to the next view I allso transfer data and I have a problem with the sections.

Let's say my section 0 has 2 row and section 1 has 1 row.
How do I check the section 1 rows?

before storybaords and preper for segue I did

```
row = indexPath.row;

if (section == 0)
{
    if (row == 0)
        data = @"Zero";

    if (row == 1)
        data = @"One";
}

if (section == 1)
{
    if (row == 0)
        data = @"Two";

    if (row == 1)
        data = @"Three";
}
```

and now it's not working. When i click the 0 row in section 1 it put's "Zero" into data instead of "Two"
Why is that?
How can I effectivly differ between section 0 and section 1?

Comment: If the indexPath is nil you would get section = 0 and row = 0. The code needs more context. There is nothing wrong with those if.

Comment: Maybe now the question is clearer (I add the first line of code I forgot to add). Row is not nil in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude, where is `section = indexpath.section`?
and here is a prepareForSegue example;

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    NSIndexPath *indexpath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
//    indexpath.section
//    indexpath.row
}
```

Comment: I will try that when I get home, I think i tried it allready but I am willing to try again.

Comment: Tnx!
My problem was "indexPathForCell:sender" that you said, I wrote "indexPathForRow:sender". Now the "if section" is working great!

Answer (score 0):

1. You should set your data displayed in the cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.
2. You simply link the prototype cell in IB to the next view controller with a Push Segue.
3. You then use `prepareForSegue` to pass to the new view controller the data it needs.

The correct `section` and `row` parameters will be in the `indexPath` variable.

Comment: Tnx Mundi, that is exactly what I did.
But I want to pass diffrent data when diffrent sections is pressed. and the only way I can differ between cell's is the "row" only and not by sections.

That is why when I press section 0, row 0 I get the same result as pressing section 1, row 0 and the result should be different.

Comment: No. You can check `indexPath.section` and `indexPath.row`.